# Erlang supervising an UDP listener

Tags: erlang

I am learning Erlang. I want to make a UDP Listener that will be supervised by a supervisor. So if the listener process goes down supervisor will restart the process. Initially I just made a simple UDP listener which works as expected.

```
startudplistener() ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(9000,[binary,{active,false}]),
    Pid = spawn(pdmanager,udplistener,[Socket]),
    {ok, Pid}.

udplistener(Socket) ->
    {ok,Packet} = gen_udp:recv(Socket,0),
    spawn(pdmanager,handleudp,[Packet]),
    udplistener(Socket).

handleudp(Packet) ->
    {_,_, Msg} = Packet,
    io:format("I have got message : ~s ~n",[Msg]),
    {handeling, Packet}.
```

So, what I want to do is to monitor the udplistener process. For this first I modified my module to a gen_server one. Write a supervisor module afterwards. My supervisor looks like this:

```
-module(pdmanager_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).

-export([start_link/1]).
-export([init/1]).

start_link(Port) ->
supervisor:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, Port).

init(Port) ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(Port, [binary, {active, false}]),
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 5, 60},
        [{listener,
            {pdmanager, start_link, [Socket]},
            permanent, 1000, worker, [pdmanager]}
        ]}}.
```

So what Im trying to so is to, open up a new udp socket and pass it to my server and the server will keep on listening to the socket while the supervisor will monitor it. So I came up with the following code.

```
start_link(Socket) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, pdmanager}, pdmanager, Socket, []).

init(Socket) ->
    io:format("UDP Server starting ~n",[]),
    spawn_link(pdmanager,udplistener,[Socket]),
    {ok, #state{socket=Socket}}.
```

I am a bit confused with spawn_link that I added within my init function. spawn_link is opening up another process, however it is making a link with the calling process. As per my understanding my supervisor will monitor the calling process here. So, how would my supervisor behave incase my udplistener goes down? If it doesn't work the way I am expecting (im expecting it will restart my server) what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your supervisor init callback implementation that creates a socket and passes it to the worker is a problem.

Apart from the exceptional case of a release upgrade your supervisor init callback will actually only be called once ever, so creating the socket in the supervisor init and passing it to the worker means there is never any mechanism for the socket to be reopened. If however you open the socket in the init callback of your gen_server worker, any problems with the socket will get solved when the worker restarts.

The next problem is you are using the socket in inactive mode. Sockets in inactive mode are really only useful and good for a relatively bare process (i.e. not a gen_server say), because when you call gen_udp:recv it can block while waiting for data to arrive... and this means the gen_server is blocked and unable to service anything it should. So now you're going down the OTP path, with supervisors and gen_servers, you should switch to using the socket in active mode, which means the UDP packets will be sent to your gen_server as messages. You can then receive then by way of your handle_info callback implementation:

```
handle_info({udp, Socket, IP, InPortNo, Packet}, #state{socket=Socket}) ->
    io:format("whooopie, got a packet ~p~n", [Packet]),
```

If your gen_server worker dies, that's fine, the port will go too, and the supervisor will start a new worker which will just reopen the socket and continue receiving again...

Also in your workers init, after opening the socket, note that the socket is actually a port, you should probably link to it by calling erlang:link/1, like this:

```
{ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(9000,[binary,{active,true}]),
erlang:link(Socket),
```

I'm not absolutely sure if gen_udp will do this anyway for you, but I can't see that it says so in the docs, and better safe than sorry. This now means if the port dies but not your worker, the link will cause your worker to also die, and the supervisor will restart your worker, which will restart your port. If you want to avoid your worker dying where you can you can trap exits instead, but simply allowing your worker to die fits better with Erlangs fail early principal IMO, and it means if your socket open is failing constantly, the supervisor will hit its restart intensity and do something different instead of letting your worker mindlessly going on forever trying to reopen the socket. So do that for now and change your strategy later if you have cause.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your response. really appreciate. I didnt get the handle_info thing. I learned handle_info deals  with asynchronous calls sent to the process directly using (!). So is it like with active mode the udp packets will be sent to my server process like that ? no need to do gen_udp:recv/2 ? Also, you mentioned "gen_udp:recv it can block while waiting for data to arrive" however, I spawned a new process where I called the gen_udp:recv() should it still block?

Comment: Also, regarding the socket you mentioned, " This now means if the port dies but not your worker, the link will cause your worker to also die"; in my code I used spawn_link. I learned spawn_link starts up a new process and  links it with the parent process. Does it work the same way like if the child dies that will cause the parent to die aswell ?

Comment: Yes, when you open your socket you can imagine it to be like a process, receiving the UDP data on your behalf and sending it on to you. A port isn't a process, but has some similarities. Yes you can spawn the recv (I didn't realise this was your intent here), it will still block, but block the spawned process instead, but you would have to send the Data received back to the parent gen_server with a message to do something useful with it (but there's no point because active mode will do that for you), or do something in the spawned process (but that wouldn't really fit with OTP).

Comment: In your supervisor you specify `{pdmanager, start_link, [Socket]}`, so the supervisor starts your gen_server as pdmanager:start_link(Socket) which calls gen_server:start_link, which spawns the gen_server and links to it (probably calls spawn_link) -- thus the supervisor becomes linked to your gen_server and can supervise it (because supervisor traps the death and takes the action of restarting your gen_server instead of, by default dying itself). By linking to your port you extend the chain of supervision from gen_server to port/socket, except just dying in this case is good enough.